# Alpha blending in Direct3D 9. Some of the primitives aren't rendering behind the texture

Tags: directx, alpha, direct3d, blending

I enabled alpha blending in my game, but some of the primitives aren't rendering behind the transparent texture.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Here are my render states:

```
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, true);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_CW);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(15, 15, 15));
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS, TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE, TRUE);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_SRCALPHA);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVSRCALPHA);
d3ddevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_ADD);

d3ddevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
d3ddevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLORARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);
d3ddevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAOP, D3DTOP_MODULATE);
d3ddevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_ALPHAARG1, D3DTA_TEXTURE);

d3ddevice->SetTextureStageState( 0, D3DTSS_TEXTURETRANSFORMFLAGS, D3DTTFF_DISABLE );

d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MINFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MAGFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
d3ddevice->SetSamplerState(0, D3DSAMP_MIPFILTER, D3DTEXF_NONE);
```

Comment: I don't understand your screenshots. Where is the transparent texture? If you want to draw objects behind something transparent, you have to draw them first. Otherwise the depth test will discard those pixels.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the transparent objects still get written to the depth buffer and therefore block objects which lie behind them from being rendered. There are (at least) two ways to solve this.

1. Sort all transparent objects in your scene such that they are rendered from back to front. You need to do this in your code, D3D won't handle this for you. [Here is an MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/02/18/depth-sorting-alpha-blended-objects.aspx) on this.
2. It looks that all objects that you are rendering are either fully transparent or fully opaque at any given point. In this case, there is a simpler way to deal with transparency: you can use alpha testing to discard all fragments which have 0 alpha (or alpha below a certain threshold, say 128). [Here is an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to do this. If you are using shaders, you can use the `discard` command to discard all transparent fragments.